# Why is the main container behind the nav?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to replicate this starter template: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/starter-template/

**The contents of my index.html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap 4</title>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,800">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </nav>

              <main role="main" class="container">

                <div class="starter-template">
                  <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
                  <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
                </div>

              </main><!-- /.container -->

    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I inspect my own index.html file, it looks a bit different(text not centered and you can't see Bootstrap starter template, even though, it is present in the HTML) than in the example, even though I copied the same code. More exactly, my main section is behind the nav and not below, like in the example link:

[image: Issue]

I mention that no custom styles have been added that affect that could affect that main section.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `fixed-top`

> Position an element at the top of the viewport, from edge to edge. *Be sure you understand the ramifications of fixed position in your project; you may need to add additional CSS*. - [bootstrap-4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/position/#fixed-top)

---

`fixed-top` removes the `element` that you use it for, from the normal flow of the content, and, hence, the `element` will overlay the other content

To fix the issue, you need to push down the `main` content equal or larger than the height of the `fixed-top` element. You can do so by setting the `padding-top` of the `body` equal or larger than the `fixed-top element's height`. For example, if the `fixed-top element's height` is `72px`, padding-top of body should be, at least, `72px`. If you wish, you can use `relative` units: `padding-top: 4.5rem;` instead of `padding-top: 72px;`.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 72px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<main role="main" class="container">

  <div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>

</main>
```

---

This is what both [`bootstrap-3`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) and [`bootstrap-4`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/navbar-fixed/) has done. I recommend you to inspect it yourself.

---

## Update

You may find these two link useful.

- [w3schools - How to - fixed menu](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp)
- [teamtreehouse - div hiddne below fixed position navbar](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/div-hidden-below-fixed-position-navbar-clearfix-issues-with-css)

Answer (score -1):

In the example template mentioned, there is a padding top of 5em to the body tag. Please try giving it.

```
body {
    padding-top: 5rem;
}
```